# How do you randomly generate a dataset with categorical variables in R?

Tags: r, random, dataset, categorical-data, levels

There has been a question asked previously in the forum on something similar, however it doesn't quite go into enough detail for my issue.

I'm trying to generate a random dataset with 8 columns and 50,000 rows. Each column must be a categorical variable (my example, breed of dog) with 3 levels (example, colour), resulting in approx. equal proportions.

The line of code below does exactly what I'm looking for, but how do you alter this to fit the following values?

breeds of dog, instead of "8" - (Poodle, Labrador, Pug, Chihuahua, Collie, Shitzu, Bulldog, Lurcher)

colours, instead of "LETTERS" - (brown, black, white)

```r
df <- data.frame(replicate(8,sample(LETTERS[1:3], 50000, replace = TRUE)))
```

Any help is much appreicated, thank you.

Comment: `data.frame(replicate(8,sample(c("Poodle", "Labrador", "Pug", "Chihuahua", "Collie", "Shitzu", "Bulldog", "Lurcher"), 50000, replace = TRUE)))`?

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks but unfortunately not. I'm looking for my columns to be named each dog breed and the rows to be a random colour.

Comment: If you set `my_col <- c("Poodle", "Labrador", "Pug", "Chihuahua", "Collie", "Shitzu", "Bulldog", "Lurcher")` and then `my_lev <- c("brown", "black", "white")` you can create the data.frame by: `df <- data.frame(replicate(length(my_col), sample(my_lev, 50000, replace = TRUE)))` and then set the names by: `names(df) <- my_col` ... will that work for you?

Comment: Yes Ben thank you! :D Do you also know how to produce a table to verify the proportions of each value?

Comment: You could try `apply(df, 2, table)`...or if you want % by column you can try `prop.table(apply(df, 2, table), 2)`